# How to only allow a list of dynamically added inputs not have the same number value chosen by the front end user

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dynamically created un ordered list. Each list item has an image an input field type:number and a label element. I already have javascript only allowing a user to enter a number 1-10; But now I want to allow a user to only give each image a unique rating, so in other words a user couldn't rate two images both 9.

[image: Example of the list]

This is my jQuery code to append the images to select from when they are checked in a different section:

```
$('#confirm').click(function(){
   $('#checkedImageContainer').removeClass('hidden');

   $(this).prop('disabled', true);

   $("input[name='tool']").each(function () {
      if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        $('.checkedImageList').append('<li>
           <img src="' + $(this).parent('li').find('img').attr('src') + '">
           <input id="rateInput" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10">
           <label id="RateButton">Rate</label></li>');
      }
   });
}
```

And this is the place in my HTML where this `<ul>` lives:

```
<div id="checkedImageContainer" class="hidden col-md-4">
   <div class="text-center">
      <h3>Now rate your favorite Images!!(#1-10)</h3>
      <ul class="checkedImageList"></ul>
      <button id="guessCheck">That's MY Opini0n</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When they type in the number, run a check against the other two input box values, and if another one matches the current one, throw an error or highlight the box and throw a message up

Answer (score 1):

using clearshots suggestion of check against other inputs.

here is a fiddle, you can't have duplicate entries in the list of inputs.

https://jsfiddle.net/d9grwkgn/2/

```
$('input').change(function() {
  if ($('input').not(this).map(function() {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get().indexOf($(this).val()) >= 0)
    $(this).val('');
})
```

Comment: I tried changing ^^^ $('input') to $('#rateInput') trying to be more specific but in didn't work(any suggestions why that might be?), and then I tried your suggestion which I should of did right from the start.... andddd it worked perfectly. Thanks much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#confirm').click(function(){

var rates = [];

$('.checkedImageList').find('input').each(function() {
    rates.push(this.value);
});

var ratesSorted = rates.sort(); 

for (var i = 0; i < ratesSorted.length - 1; i++) {
    if (ratesSorted[i + 1] == ratesSorted[i]) {
        return false;
    } 
}

$('#checkedImageContainer').removeClass('hidden');
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
$("input[name='tool']").each(function () {
if($(this).is(':checked')){
     $('.checkedImageList').append('<li><img 
src="'+$(this).parent('li').find('img').attr('src') +'"><input 
id="rateInput" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10"><label 
id="RateButton">Rate</label></li>');

}
});
```

This will block the button from executing your code if there are any duplicates in your inputs.